# How to say "to put you on the spot"?

Tags: перевод

There's an English [expression](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+on+the+spot) "to put somebody on the spot" which, among other meanings includes following one: "to ask someone forthright questions".

For instance, if you are asking someone about some hard decision he/she was supposed to make, an answer can be: "Don't put me on the spot, I have not decided anything yet".

My question is - what will be the best match in Russian. 
Off the top of my head it's something like "не хочется вам досаждать / вас пытать раньше времени" but I guess there are some better alternatives out there.

Comment: I would translate your example as *не дави на меня*

Comment: Also "Хватит меня *допрашивать*!"

Comment: Or "Не стой (у меня) над душой!", this one can refer not only to uncomfortable questions, but also to other kinds of impatient and irritating behaviour.

Comment: Also "Не капай мне на мозги!" may fit.

Comment: @Shabunc: Actually to put someone on the spot is not to pressure them, which is what your example sounds like. It's actually asking someone a question that's awkward for them to answer because of those present, or because of touchy circumstances, or coercing them to do something they wouldn't normally do by making them feel awkward. For example, asking A if you can take B to his party - with B present! You would be putting A on the spot, because, unless he's very cruel, it would be awkward for him to say no in front of B, even if he didn't want him to go.

Comment: In another example, say you got a big Christmas bonus from your boss. Then in front of your coworkers, your secretary congratulates you and informs you that her children won't be getting any Christmas presents this year since her husband left her and she can't make ends meet. You coworkers give you knowing looks and put you on the spot, so you give your secretary your bonus. In Russian there must be an expression that means "embarrassing someone into doing or saying something." At any rate, that's what the expression means in English.

Comment: @CocoPop excellent clarification, thank you, now it's way clearer!

Comment: My pleasure) I'd be curious to know how to say this in Russian, but I don't know enough Russian to judge from the answers below.

Answer (score 4):

> Ставить в неловкое положение
>
> Загонять в угол
>
> Припереть к стен(к)е

Answer (score 2):

Don't put me on the spot, I have not decided anything yet

Не дави на меня, я еще не решил/определился.